# In the latest version of html2canvas I'm having an issue with Arabic being rendered incorrectly as an unreadable mess

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4, html2canvas

#### Bug report:

I'm using bootstrap 4 and angular 11, though this issue seems to be directly related to the package rather than any of those, I've tried:

- Changing the css **text-align** to **left**, **right** and **center**
- Changing the lang to **ar** in  as well as setting the encoding to **utf-8**
- Changing the css **direction** to **ltr** and **rtl**

[image]

#### This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="text_card" class="card p-5">

                <h1  >السلام عليكم</h1>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveTable()">تخزين</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div id="display_card">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### This is the method that I wrote to print:

```
  saveTable() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#text_card"))
      .then(canvas => {
        document.querySelector("#display_card").appendChild(canvas);
      });
  }
```

#### Specifications:

- html2canvas version tested with: html2canvas 1.0.0-rc.7
- Browser & version: Chrome Version 86.0.4240.198 and Firefox 81.0 (64-bit)
- Operating system: Windows 10

Comment: Could you be suffering from the way ligatures are, or aren’t, treated? See for example [link] https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/1085 The image looks as though you have some overwriting/concatenation. Also can you reproduce the problem in plain HTML/JS, with no bootstrap, angular or other libraries?

Comment: I've just tried it without angular/bootstrap and it renders perfectly so it is something that is altered within them that we have to look for. There is quite a bit of CSS that html2canvas can't deal with properly see [link]https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features.html

Comment: I've now tried it with angular/bootstrap and it's looking OK. The only difference seems to be that without bootstrap I don't get the text 'decorated' in some way. Can you put up a whole example, including the library loads, that shows the problem?